# How to pkill from a script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, shell-script, dash

How can I write a script that basically just runs `pkill -HUP inetd`? I want to restart `inetd` via a script so I can schedule it to run at a particular time. I tried to write it myself, but I'm getting a "Hangup" error.

Comment: Could you show us a example of what you've tried? Maybe someone could show you what you did wrong, just asking us to script for you sounds lazy. You may learn something useful for the future.

Comment: What exactly did you do (are you running the script from a shell? from a crontab?), and what was the exact error message you got? I can't think of an use case where you would need a script instead of just running `pkill` directly

Comment: I tried following mini script but it doesn't seems to work.                                                          #!/usr/local/bin/bash
PKILL="/usr/bin/pkill -HUP inetd"
MAIL="/usr/bin/mail"
USER="ian@mail-server.com"
sudo $PKILL
$MAIL -s "inetd restarted on mail-server" $USER < /dev/null
exit 0

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @Ian Edit your question. Copy-paste your script, the way you run it, and the error message you get.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
PID=`pidof inetd`
MAIL="/usr/bin/mail"
USER="ian@mail-server.com"
sudo kill -s HUP $PID
$MAIL -s "inetd restarted on mail-server" $USER < /dev/null
exit 0
```

If `pidof` is available.

Comment: Thanks llua, it works with no issues. Just out of curiosity can you tell why we can't use pkill instead kill? Thanks once again. Ian

Comment: Do you mind pasting the full output of the error? or was the full error returned to you was "Hangup".

Comment: Sorry I was away for few days. Yes, "Hangup" was the total message. I am running the script on Solaris 5.7 by the way. Thanks for your assistance.